# php crop image without upload it

Tags: php, upload, photo, crop

```
//Your Image
$imgSrc = "image.jpg"; 

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgSrc);

$myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc); 

if ($width > $height) {  
    $y = 0; 
    $x = ($width - $height) / 2; 
    $smallestSide = $height; 
} else {  
    $x = 0;  
    $y = ($height - $width) / 2;
    $smallestSide = $width; 
} 

$thumbSize = 100; 
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbSize, $thumbSize);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $myImage, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbSize, $thumbSize, $smallestSide, $smallestSide);

//Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
```

PAGE REVIEW  :

```
<?php

$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");
while($row_img = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
$img_url=$row_img['3']; ?>
        <img src="/<? echo $img_url; ?>"  />        
<?php } ?>
```

I want to use this code with while to view my photo from database.

my image name in db `$imgSrc=$img_url;` that is row name.

Thank you

Comment: It seems like there is a lot of code missing from this.  Judging by the method names it sounds like you're creating an image instead of retrieving it from the database.  You might want to clarify exactly what you're trying to do.  The better your question, the better the answers :)

Comment: Look at the code now, i edit it :)

Comment: So do you want to: 1 retrieve the image file name from the database? 2. crop it? 3. display the cropped image?

Comment: Yes Exactly, These are the steps that I want to apply.

Comment: Besides your problem you should think about caching the created resized image on your server (within your script). Otherwise it gets resized on every request which costs processor power and slows down the image loading in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
$url = "http://localhost/sample.jpg";

$src = file_get_contents($url);

$myImage = imagecreatefromstring($src); 


if ($width > $height) {  
 $y = 0; 
 $x = ($width - $height) / 2; 
 $smallestSide = $height; 
} else {  
 $x = 0;  
 $y = ($height - $width) / 2;
 $smallestSide = $width; 
} 

$thumbSize = 100; 

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbSize, $thumbSize);

imagecopyresampled($thumb, $myImage, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbSize, $thumbSize, $smallestSide, $smallestSide);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($myImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-2.jpg";

$src = file_get_contents($url);

$filename = end(explode('/', $url ));

$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');

fwrite($handle, $src);

fclose($handle);

$myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); 

//do your other stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

**create a file names resizer.php and write down the codes below to that file(resizer.php)**

```
class Resizer {

    public $image_to_resize;
    public $new_width;
    public $new_height;
    public $ratio;

    public function resize() {

        if(!file_exists($this->image_to_resize)) {
            exit("File ".$this->image_to_resize." does not exist.");
        }

        $info = getimagesize($this->image_to_resize);

        if(empty($info)) {
            exit("The file ".$this->image_to_resize." doesn't seem to be an image.");
        }

        $width = $info[0];
        $height = $info[1];
        $mime = $info['mime'];

        if($this->ratio) {
            if (isset($this->new_width)) {
                $factor = (float)$this->new_width / (float)$width;
                $this->new_height = $factor * $height;
            }
            else if (isset($this->new_height)) {
                $factor = (float)$this->new_height / (float)$height;
                $this->new_width = $factor * $width;
            }
            else    exit("neither new height or new width has been set");
        }

        $type = substr(strrchr($mime, '/'), 1);

        switch (strtolower($type)) {
            case 'jpeg':
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
                $image_save_func = 'imagejpeg';
                $new_image_ext = 'jpg';
                break;

            case 'png':
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefrompng';
                $image_save_func = 'imagepng';
                $new_image_ext = 'png';
                break;

            case 'bmp':
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefrombmp';
                $image_save_func = 'imagebmp';
                $new_image_ext = 'bmp';
                break;

            case 'gif':
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromgif';
                $image_save_func = 'imagegif';
                $new_image_ext = 'gif';
                break;

            case 'vnd.wap.wbmp':
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromwbmp';
                $image_save_func = 'imagewbmp';
                $new_image_ext = 'bmp';
                break;

            case 'xbm':
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromxbm';
                $image_save_func = 'imagexbm';
                $new_image_ext = 'xbm';
                break;

            default:
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
                $image_save_func = 'imagejpeg';
                $new_image_ext = 'jpg';
        }

        // New Image
        $image_c = imagecreatetruecolor($this->new_width, $this->new_height);

        $new_image = $image_create_func($this->image_to_resize);

        imagecopyresampled($image_c, $new_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->new_width, $this->new_height, $width, $height);

    header("Content-Type: ".$mime);
    $image_save_func($image_c);
        $process = $image_save_func($image_c);

    }
}

// Default Width and Height
$def_width = 100;
$def_height = 100;

// Get Variables from Get
$image_file_path = $_GET['image_file'];
$width = ( (isset($_GET['width']) && intval($_GET['width'])!=0) ? $_GET['width'] : $def_width );
$height = ( (isset($_GET['height']) && intval($_GET['height'])!=0) ? $_GET['height'] : $def_height );

// Use Resizer Class
$image = new Resizer();

// Set New Cropped Dimensions
$image->new_width = $width;
$image->new_height = $height;

// Path of Image to Resize
$image->image_to_resize = $image_file_path;

// Maintains Image Ratio
$image->ratio = true;

$image->resize();
```

**resizer.php file usage**

```
<?php

$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");

while($row_img = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
     $img_url = $row_img['3'];
?>
     <img src="resizer.php?image_file=<?php echo $img_url; ?>&width={NEW_WIDTH_FOR_IMAGE}&height={NEW_HEIGHT_FOR_IMAGE}" />
<?php
}
?>
```

check it out...